# Где достать все существующие вещи Dota2 в формате json

Tags: php, json, steam-web-api, steam

Весь вопрос содержится в заголовке. Инвентарь конкретного пользователя можно достать по ссылке `http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/steamid/570/2?l=english`, но где достать все существующие вещи?

Comment: https://github.com/kronusme/dota2-api/blob/master/data/items.json

Comment: Речь идет о вещах, которые можно покупать, обменивать и тд

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все вещи можно достать из любой базы предметов на ваш вкус.  Для Dota2 я использовал базу сайта market.dota2.net, вот его API  https://market.dota2.net/docs/

Сам Steam не предоставляет полных баз предметов по играм. Вам нужно их искать на торговых площадках, игровых сайтах, есть просто базы предметов с API для доступа к ним.

Информация о предмете может отличаться от базы к базе, но если вам нужна полная информация о каждом предмете, которую предоставляет Steam, то в этом случае вы должны обновлять свою базу сканируя инвентарь авторизованных через Steam на вашем сайте пользователей.

Итак: Если вам нужен просто перечень всех предметов, вам нужно обращаться к сторонним торговым площадкам, если вам нужна цена предмета, то же самое.
Но если вам нужны ссылки на изображения, полное описание предметов и тд. То без Steam не обойтись, и такую инфу можно добывать только по чуть-чуть "разглядывая" предметы через инвентарь авторизованных пользователей